# Proving that a polynomial is the generating idempotent of the repetition code of length $n$

Tags: coding-theory, idempotents

First of all, we consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}$, with $|\mathbb{F}|=q$, and a natural number $n$ that is relatively prime to $q$. 
We also consider the quotient ring $\mathcal{R}_n = \mathbb{F}[x]/<x^n-1>$. 

I want to prove that the polynomial $g(x)=\frac{1}{n}(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1)$ is a generating idempotent of the repetition code of length $n$ over $\mathbb{F}$. 

So far, I have managed to prove that $g(x)$ is an idempotent element of the ring $\mathcal{R}_n$. 
I also know that $x^n-1 = n(x-1)g(x)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the definition of the polynomial $g(x)$. In particular, what does $\frac1n$ mean in $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: I'm not really sure to be honest. That is how the question was given to me

Comment: @AndreasLenz $\frac 1n$ means the multiplicative inverse of the _field integer_ $n$  (or $n \bmod p$ where $p$ is the characteristic of the field). Since $n$ is given to be relatively prime to $q$, we are guaranteed that $n  \bmod p \neq 0$ and so $n$ does have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Are there words other than repetitions in the code generated by $g(x)$? Why, or why not?